# Condition: positive and negative number in RPG

Tags: rpgle, rpg

When I enter a negative number in my console, I don't get the display !
For example if enter the value ´-2´, I don't get the message 'negative`

In positive and null c'est ok

[image]

```
 H
 D Number          S              2S 0

  *
  /Free

      dsply 'Enter your number please : ' '' Number;

      If (Number > 0);
         dsply 'Positive';

      ElseIf (Number = 0);
         dsply 'Null';

      Else;
         dsply 'Negative';
      ENDIF;

      *inlr = *on;

  /End-Free
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the RPGLE reference for the DSPLY op-code I found this excerpt:

> If a non-float numeric field is entered with a length greater than the number of digits in the result field
> and the rightmost character is not a minus sign (-), an error is detected and a second wait occurs. The
> user must key in the field again.

It seems the DSPLY op-code expects the minus sign to be trailing and not leading.

Comment: Ah yesss, thank you for your help. I understood.

Answer (score 1):

If you do F1 (help) on the DSPLY message, it shows this:

```
Message ID . . . . . . :   RNQ5337       Severity . . . . . . . :   00         
Message type . . . . . :   Sender copy                                         
Date sent  . . . . . . :   12/18/20      Time sent  . . . . . . :   12:42:16   
                                                                               
Message . . . . :   DSPLY  Enter your number please :      0                   
Cause . . . . . :   This is an inquiry message originated from RPG procedure   
  MY_PGM in program MY_LIB/MY_PGM. The program is expecting a numeric 
  input field with a maximum length of 2 digits with 0 decimal positions.  Do  
  not type in a decimal point when entering data. When entering negative data, 
  type a negative sign ('-') immediately after the last digit of the data.
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [%dec()](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_73/rzasd/bbdec.htm) to convert a numeric value in a string to a numeric variable.  That will allow your users to place the negative sign on the left or the right.  This might be a friendlier way of using the [DSPLY](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_73/rzasd/zzdsply.htm) opcode.

```
**FREE
   //simple demo, not worrying about exceptions

   dcl-s myStr  varchar(5);
   dcl-s myNum  packed(3:0);


   dsply 'Enter your number please : ' '' myStr;
   myNum = %dec(myStr:3:0);

   Select;
   When (myNum > 0);
     dsply 'Positive';

   When (myNum = 0);
     dsply 'Zero';     // not the same a null ;-)

   Other;
     dsply 'Negative';
   EndSl;

   *inlr = *on;
   RETURN;
```